# Example for how to do reading AND writing between two endpoints with libevent?

Tags: c++, c, networking, tcp, libevent

I have been struggling with how to set this up.  I have found information online how to do reading, and how to do writing, but I'm confused how to do both reading and writing.  Do I need to start up two event base loops?  Or can I use one somehow?  Here is an example of code for sending that I found online for example (callback functions omitted):

```
int err;

#ifdef _WIN32
    WORD wVersionRequested;
    WSADATA wsaData;

    /* Use the MAKEWORD(lowbyte, highbyte) macro declared in Windef.h */
    wVersionRequested = MAKEWORD(2, 2);

    err = WSAStartup(wVersionRequested, &wsaData);

    if (err != 0) {
        /* Tell the user that we could not find a usable */
        /* Winsock DLL.                                  */
        printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", err);
        return false;
    }
#endif

    struct event_base *base;
    struct bufferevent *bev;
    struct sockaddr_in sin;

    base = event_base_new();

    memset(&sin, 0, sizeof(sin));
    sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sin.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(0x7f000001); /* 127.0.0.1 */
    sin.sin_port = htons(22346); 

    bev = bufferevent_socket_new(base, -1, BEV_OPT_CLOSE_ON_FREE);

    bufferevent_setcb(bev, NULL, NULL, eventcb, NULL);
    bufferevent_enable(bev, EV_READ|EV_WRITE);

    evbuffer_add_printf(bufferevent_get_output(bev), "WOOOOOOOOOOOOOO");

    if (bufferevent_socket_connect(bev,
        (struct sockaddr *)&sin, sizeof(sin)) < 0) {
        /* Error starting connection */
        bufferevent_free(bev);
        return -1;
    }

    event_base_dispatch(base);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should use `bufferevent_write()` instead of the lower level `evbuffer_add_printf()` - the former is cleaner and the underlying evbuffer might be frozen.

You also disable the read and write callbacks - so you won't get a callback when you can read from your bufferevent. Implement at least your read callback and set it via `bufferevent_setcb()`. Probably this is why you don't see anything happening.

Next, probably you either:

- Want to send something to the peer when connected - use `bufferevent_write()` when you get the connected event (`BEV_EVENT_CONNECTED`) in your `eventcb` callback.
- Expect to receive something from the peer once connected - your read callback will be called in this case.

Comment: I understand the need to implement the read callback, I just wanted to post a sample for writing.  Do I need to create two bufferevent sockets, one for reading and one for writing?  That's the main part I am confused about.  My understanding of TCP isn't that great but I think I will need two socket conections, correct?

Comment: Nope, you need one socket and one bufferevent. You can write to it to send data, and when your read callback is called you can read from it.